# How to see co-relation between course grades?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server. Please help me find the Co-relation between the grades for two courses.

I want to find that which Student got 'A' Grade in 'Computer Programming' who had an 'A' grade in Introduction to Computer too.

This is how the data looks like:

```
RollNum | CGPA | Status     | Name                              | Grade
410     | 2.6  | Completed  | Introduction to Computer Science  | A  
410     | 2.6  | Completed  | Computer Programming              | A-  
422     | 3.2  | Completed  | Introduction to Computer Science  | A 
422     | 3.2  | Completed  | Computer Programming              | A  
223     | 3.52 | Completed  | Introduction to Computer Science  | A 
223     | 3.52 | Completed  | Computer Programming              | A 
521     | 1.2  | Completed  | Introduction to Computer Science  | B+ 
521     | 1.2  | Completed  | Computer Programming              | A-
....
....
```

this is the Query that I am Writing:

```
SELECT [RollNum],[CGPA],[Status],[Name],[FinalGrade]
 FROM db
     where Name ='Introduction to Computer Science' and FinalGrade='A' 
  and (Name='Computer Programming' and FinalGrade= 'A' )
```

Please help me, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How is your current query not working?  Also, you should read up on database normalization.  I see some problems with the way your data is structured.

Comment: +1 - just to get rid of the -1 as even though this question is very specific (local) it is still well structured with enough detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT qCP.*
FROM (SELECT RollNum, CGPA, Status, Name, FinalGrade
      FROM db
      WHERE Name = 'Computer Programming' 
      AND FinalGrade = 'A') qCP
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT RollNum 
     FROM db 
     WHERE Name = 'Introduction to Computer Science' 
     AND FinalGrade = 'A') qIntro
ON qCP.RollNum = qIntro.RollNum
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
select RollNum
from db
where [Name] in ('Introduction to Computer Science', 'Computer Programming')
  and [Grade] = 'A'
group by RollNum
having count(distinct name) = 2
```

This is known as [Relational Division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) and will return the student `RollNum` where they took both classes and received an `A` in each class.

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/adfc1/4)

If you want more than just the `RollNum`, then you can use the above query in a `WHERE EXISTS`:

```
select [RollNum], [CGPA], [Status], [Name], [Grade]
from db d1
where exists (select RollNum
              from db d2
              where [Name] in ('Introduction to Computer Science', 'Computer Programming')
                and [Grade] = 'A'
                and d1.rollnum = d2.rollnum
              group by RollNum
              having count(distinct name) = 2);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b7a4e/2)

Answer (score 1):

If using SQL server, I would use

```
Select [RollNum],[CGPA],[Status],[Name],[FinalGrade]
from db
where [Name] in ('Introduction to Computer Science', 'Computer Programming')
and [FinalGrade] = 'A'
```

Comment: This will give students that got an A in either class, not both.